# I need help in C program

Tags: c

How Do I check all the if statement? is there any code I can use? I even tried to use loop but since I just started programing I fail so bad. I need to check all the statement and if its true it should executed not when the first one is true they will ignore the other one

```
int stkcommon[5]={50,30,5,49,50};
int a;

{
if(stkcommon[0]<50){
printf("The Number 1");
}

else if(stkcommon[1]<50)
{
printf("The Number 2");
}

else if(stkcommon[2]<50)
{
printf("The Number 3");
}

 else if(stkcommon[3]<50)
{
printf("The Number 4");
}

 else if(stkcommon[4]<50)
{
  printf("The Number 5");
   }
```

Comment: Change them all to simply `if` instead of `else if`

Comment: use switch and case stkcommon[0] < 50 ....

Comment: You're going to need to learn how to do a for loop eventually, what if your next array has 500 numbers instead of 5?

Comment: for(i = 0; i < 5;i++){(if stkcommon[i] < 50){ print("The Number %s",i.tosting() ) } }

Comment: @鄭有維 can you elaborate on the switch case solution you mentioned?

Comment: I already Though about that I dont know why I didnt try. 
it may looks likes like nothing to you but its really help me a lot thank you.
I just started programing last night and I didnt get enough sleep because of that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your else if into if

```
    int stkcommon[5]={50,30,5,49,50};
    int a;

    {
    if(stkcommon[0]<50){
        printf("The Number 1");
    }

    if(stkcommon[1]<50){
        printf("The Number 2");
    }

    if(stkcommon[2]<50){
        printf("The Number 3");
    }

    if(stkcommon[3]<50){
        printf("The Number 4");
    }

    if(stkcommon[4]<50){
        printf("The Number 5");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
   if(stkcommon[i]<50){
      printf("The Number %d",i+1);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think he also need the else if behaviour

Comment: he is asking for a simplified code in checking all the if statement in the code he posted. This is the most simplified version i could think of.

Comment: He mentions in the last line *the first one is true they will ignore the other one*, the language is very confusing

Comment: I guess what he means is that his current code behaves that way. Instead of checking all, it only checks which is true and ignores the rest and what he is looking for is a code to check all statement, not only the first true statement

Answer (score 1):

I think you also want to retain the if else if behavior while checking everything in the loop.
So extending upon @JkAlombro's solution

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    if (stkcommon[i]<5){
        printf("The number %d", i+1);
        break; // So  the other conditions aren't checked
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boundary testcases to test code in general, so test if your code works as expected with stkcommmon[0] equal to -50, 0, 49, 50, and 51.

Learn to code loops and reduce the complexity of your code. Then you only need to check one IF, and if it works for a few cases, it will likely work for all cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{
 int stkcommon[5]={50,30,5,49,50};

 for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
    if (stkcommon[i] < 50)
      {
       printf("Value at location %d is less than 50. It has value %d\n", i, stkcommon[5]);
       break; // Break so  the other array elements are not checked (if desired)
      }


}
```